# Vim neocomplcache: disable usage prompt

Tags: python, vim, vim-plugin, neocomplcache

I am using Vim with neocomplcache plugin, its feature of usage prompt while completion confused me so much.

It behaved like this: I typed `<C-X><C-U>` when the cursor was at the end of `os.path.`, then not only completion candidates was listed under the line, but also a horizontal split 
which contained docstring of the first candidate appeared
at the top. My question is: how to get rid of this feature so that I only get code completion without the usage prompt?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's all because `preview` is in `completeopt` by default, you can see its value by type
command `:set completeopt` and the result should be `completeopt=menu,preview`.

What we need is just `menu`, so cut the `preview`, add this line in your vimrc:

```
set completeopt-=preview
```

vim help reference:

```
                        *'completeopt'* *'cot'*
'completeopt' 'cot' string  (default: "menu,preview")
            global
            {not available when compiled without the
            |+insert_expand| feature}
            {not in Vi}
    A comma separated list of options for Insert mode completion
    |ins-completion|.  The supported values are:

       menu     Use a popup menu to show the possible completions.  The
            menu is only shown when there is more than one match and
            sufficient colors are available.  |ins-completion-menu|

       menuone  Use the popup menu also when there is only one match.
            Useful when there is additional information about the
            match, e.g., what file it comes from.

       longest  Only insert the longest common text of the matches.  If
            the menu is displayed you can use CTRL-L to add more
            characters.  Whether case is ignored depends on the kind
            of completion.  For buffer text the 'ignorecase' option is
            used.

       preview  Show extra information about the currently selected
            completion in the preview window.  Only works in
            combination with "menu" or "menuone".
```

Comment: It seems you were in stackoverflow off-line mode.